# deploy asp.net project as executable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I'm planning on creating some sort of "media-manager".
Add your bluray/dvd collection and it downloads metadata and lists your collection in a nice way and so on.

It's supposed to run on a NAS/Homeserver running Windows 8 and i want to access it via a webinterface.

ASP.NET using Web-Api seems like a good way to go.
However, it would be great to deploy the website as an executable.

For example: A friend want's to use the application too. I give him an installer and afterwards, he just needs to doubleclick the .exe and a webserver (IIS Express?) and the website boot up automatically.

Is this possible? (and if, how?)

Thanks

Comment: You can use Self-host WebAPI and a HTML page as user interface! IIS Express comes with Visual Studio, so you can't do this way!

Comment: Thank you. it even is explained on the asp.net homepage...thing's can be so easy

Comment: You can publish the application and share the published copy. Then taht copy configure with IIS and can access the application.

Answer (score 0):

Well, of course you could write an installer that installs a webserver (like casini) and then install the Website to this Server and all is installed locally but I don't recommend that. That installer Need more work then the Website.
You are better of with Hosting you Website in a public place like Windows azure and implement your Website in a way that a user can logon and sees it's DVDs. Another users sees other DVDs. Or give him Access to your homeserver with dyndns.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can add a "Web Setup" project in your asp project to build a msi package and custom what do you want step by step .
This will generate a "installWebSite.msi" file at the end. Just double click it and follow the website installation 
You can see a good presentation here ->

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/06/15/tip-trick-creating-packaged-asp-net-setup-programs-with-vs-2005.aspx

[image]